# how to maintain selected checkbox in different pages

Tags: javascript, checkbox

How can I maintain selected checkbox in different pages, I am not using the gridview, and I just to do this by JS or PHP, how can I do this?

Comment: What are you using on the server side? HTTP is a stateless protocol. To maintain the state, you have some options like session,url rewriting,hidden fields

Comment: url rewriting, maybe that's what I need, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Using sessions and variables in PHP you can save values over pages.